# Representation of code (C)

Tags: c, gcc, computer-science

Can you please help re-write this code. I am not able to understand how the bitwise leftshift actually works. If there is a easier way to represent this code then please let me know.

This code is to calculate the number of 1 (ones) in a bit representation of a number.

```
int numberofones( int value, int count) {

  int numchars = 8 * sizeof(int);
  int n;

  for(n = 0; n < numchars; n++)
  {
    if(value & (1 << (numchars - 1 - n))) {
     count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: No,right-shifting is sign-extended. Shifting by more than the number of bits is undefined.

Comment: @yano -- bit-shifting a negative value to the left causes undefined behavior; bit-shifting a nonnegative value to the left (so long as the result is representable) is well-defined.

Comment: ah, whoops, it's the `1` getting shifted, I was thinking `numchars` .. didn't look closely enough

Comment: @yano -- still, using `unsigned` types is a good habit when using bit-shifting operators....

Comment: @wildplasser Technically: *"The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions [...] If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined."* per section 6.5.7.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/

Comment: Play computer with a pencil and paper-trace out the execution, values, loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
int numberofones( int value) {

  int numchars = 8 * sizeof(int);
  int n;
  int count = 0 ;

  for(n = 0; n < numchars; n++)
  {
    if(value & (1 << n))
      count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```